# Android button that fades into view

Tags: android

I want to have a button that is originally invisible. I then want the button to fade into view

Here is my code

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/textFade"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:text="Sample Button" />
```

and then in the onCreate function of my activity i add

```
    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.textFade);


    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
    animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    b.setAnimation(animation);
```

But this does not work. Any ideas how i can achieve this ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should also call the start method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#start()

Answer (score 5):

Use [startAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) instead!

```
b.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```